# Provide different svn revisions for each folder present in a svn url in Jenkins

Tags: svn, jenkins, version-control

I have a parent project in SVN which has a Parent POM.
And there are several child projects within the given parent folder.
The parent POM builds all the child projects.

Now I am setting up all the builds in Jenkins, and I want to achieve the following.

1. I should be able to provide any svn revision for each of the child-project folders.
2. The parent folder will build on the latest svn revision.

To achieve the above I have tried a tweak, however it doesn't seem to work.

What I have done is:

1. Added `Jenkins` `String Parameter` for each of the Child projects. Here I pass a revision number as a variable for the Source Code management of the module. (I have added several modules with specific svn url for each of the child projects).
2. For each of the child projects, I have created `Jenkins` `List Subversion Tags`. This variable is used to pass the child folder name at build time.

> **Thing is**, suppose for a particular project I pass a revision number as parameter, and leave the parameter fields for others as blank (Also for the parent folder as blank);    what happens is Jenkins first takes checkout of the proper revision for the particular child project. But again does another update after that and checks out latest files of all child folders.
>
> > My project owners wants to select different revisions for different projects depending on what all they want to release in production.

I am very confused with how to achieve this.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood this correct your project looks something like this:

```
- toplevel-project -> HEAD
--subproject 1 -> REV A
--subproject 2 -> REV B
--subproject x -> REV X
```

Have you tried already to play around with the depth of a checkout? This should actually work. So first checkout the toplevel-project at HEAD with just the files (depth "files"). Afterwards you checkout the subprojects into the same folder at the specific revision. But this approach depends a bit of how the structure of your projects look like in the repository.

You can also checkout the parent with it's childrens and empty folders (depth "immediates") and then switch the depth of the several childrens to the specific revision with setting the new depth of this subfolder to "infinity". But if the subversion-plugin supports this behavior I haven't tried out yet.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I will give it a try.
Although, the trickery that I explained before somehow worked for me.
I am able to get checkout of the revisions I mention for some of the specific child projects. 
And for the ones I leave the fields as blank, jenkins checkout the latest rev.